# Github API - Upload an Image to Repo from base64 array

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I've successfully written a json file to a Github Repo from a web session using the Github.js API: https://github.com/michael/github

I'd like to have the user upload an image in the browser, and then save this image to the repo - so I have to save the repo as a 64 bit array  (or a Blob representing it). I've tried several options but not having success.  Can someone advise how to upload an image using [repo.writeFile()](http://michael.github.io/github/docs/2.3.0/Repository.html#writeFile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but this is working for me if I set "encode" to "false" in the repo.writeFile() options.

The string representing the file, as read from a file reader:

```
window.btoa(window.atob((reader.result.replace(/^(.+,)/, ''))));
```

Comment: Are you reading the result as data url or binary string ? or array buffer ?